# Fetch api response in chrome and firefox is different

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I called an API with the return is supposed to be a JSON object. When I run it on Google chrome, safari, edge, the return is an object which is correct. But when I try it on Mozilla, it returns a text :
`H4sIAAAAAAAA/4yOwU7rMBBF9+8rnu46RuPEbWMv2fADrNhEY3uMLJo4cp1KVdV/R0Ug2MF25tyjc0UoUeB6og5VTtuxwV2RI5zuEMq88nKZFp4FDo/HTXyu8f9TLduK738sM+cFDv6TeL0DD6HM6JBP01mWWCpc4uNJPi4cWj4LXKubdFhrDjKtUqe3GY46rFzbInW6d2BIfkjGitKajDLGsrK7kZUZyerD4InJ3GOqcJM4cYNDTz0pMkrrZ+pdT263f0GHucSc8i/Ql8hf4BDSyHtrvTrExMp4zWoU0opsSEO00SZKP8V/H91u/94DAAD//2TPZVR+AQAA`

which will return an error if I run response.json();

Anyone has the solution for this?

Here's my fetch API code

```
fetch(BASE_URL + urlPath, {
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  }
})
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
```

Here's the header request from mozilla :

```
Accept
    application/json
Accept-Encoding
    gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language
    id,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Authorization
    Bearer xxx
Cache-Control
    max-age=0
Connection
    keep-alive
Content-Type
    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host
    api-test.id
Origin
    http://localhost:3000
Referer
    http://localhost:3000/dashboard
TE
    Trailers
User-Agent
    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0
```

And this is from Chrome :

```
:authority: api-test.id
:method: GET
:path: /test/path
:scheme: https
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fr-FR;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,id;q=0.6
authorization: Bearer xxx
origin: http://localhost:3000
referer: http://localhost:3000/
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: cross-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.102 Safari/537.36
```

Thanks

Comment: your code wouldn't return anything

Comment: @JaromandaX it returns a text in the 2nd then like I mentioned above

Comment: no ... it doesn't not - there is no `return response.json()` - so where do you see these values? in the developer tools network inspector?

Comment: Did you compare the request and response headers of both to see if there's a difference?

Comment: @JaromandaX ah sorry about that, I forgot to write it. It's just an example to my real code. The point of the question is, it returns a text on Mozilla firefox which is incorrect, and it supposed to be a json object. Other browser returns a json object except mozilla

Comment: "just an example" should still work, otherwise there's nothing to help with. So, what's in the actual headers? because if you're getting a different response, the server is sending different data, and you should look at the entire response to figure out why

Comment: well, I've never had firefox receive base64 when other browsers receive JSON ... what does the response look like in the developer tools network inspector

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that's all the headers. the only thing different is the first then which is a conditional statement

Comment: @JaromandaX 
mozilla: ```H4sIAAAAAAAA/4yOwU7rMBBF9+8rnu46RuPEbWMv2fADrNhEY3uMLJo4cp1KVdV/R0Ug2MF25tyjc0UoUeB6og5VTtuxwV2RI5zuEMq88nKZFp4FDo/HTXyu8f9TLduK738sM+cFDv6TeL0DD6HM6JBP01mWWCpc4uNJPi4cWj4LXKubdFhrDjKtUqe3GY46rFzbInW6d2BIfkjGitKajDLGsrK7kZUZyerD4InJ3GOqcJM4cYNDTz0pMkrrZ+pdT263f0GHucSc8i/Ql8hf4BDSyHtrvTrExMp4zWoU0opsSEO00SZKP8V/H91u/94DAAD//2TPZVR+AQAA```
chrome : {success: true, data: []}

Comment: Could you capture request from chrome and mozila and check the request? I think each of these browsers appends some headers sometimes on its own

Comment: @Sohan done, I edit the post with header request information from 2 browsers

Comment: different referer headers ... so, are you comparing the same request even? ... `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` - clearly you aren't as your request has a different content-type header in the request

Comment: `Host: api-test.id` - cross origin request?

Comment: chrome has no host or content-type header at all ... the requests look completely unrelated

Comment: @Fitzgeral Yeh, so you look at request, Mozila is sending "Content-Type" header value as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. You need to figure out why? Also I assume this is `GET` request. 
Could you paste your fetch request code in details with options?

Comment: Also try removing `'Content-Type': 'application/json',` from request and see the result

Comment: Is this triggered by a form submission, maybe that gets `preventDefault`?

Comment: @Fitzgeral no it's not: what are the _response_ headers, too?

Answer (score 1):

please try this code:

```
fetch(BASE_URL + urlPath,{headers: {
            'authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }})
      .then(response=>response.json())
      .then(data=>{
              console.log(data);
              return data
          }
      );
```

Comment: the response is still the same on mozilla (text)

Comment: are you sure use 'then' like me same as a chain function?